# how to read varbinary max sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetUserAvatar]
    ( @userid int)  
     AS 
      BEGIN
        select avatar
          from t_user
             where (userID = @userid) AND (avatar<>null)
       end
```

and this C# code to execute this query:

```
string ConnectionString = SafaConnectionString.ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetUserAvatar", Connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    try
    {
        cmd.Connection = Connection;
        Connection.Open();            
       sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            return dt;
        else
            return null;
    }
```

It worked fine,but now returns `dt.Rows.Count == 0`.In the event that,
t_users.avatar Is not empty.
Have I got the query wrong?

Comment: maybe your table has been truncated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare `NULL` with `<>` operator use `IS` operator to validate `NULL` values

```
where userID = @userid AND avatar is not null
```